# Rotate N objects identically, but with unique variations

Tags: animation, drivers

I have over half a dozen identical objects in a scene, and I want to slowly rotate them around a single axis (their individual vertical axes) by setting parameters on each instance of the object, controlling how fast and in which direction they spin.

Custom Properties are pretty straightforward to add and define, but since I want *all* the objects to behave the same way, but rotate in different directions at different speeds, I want to be able to define a single Driver Expression (or something like it) that will take these properties from each object and plug them into an equation (hence the Expression) and apply that to the object's rotation.

Only, when I try to add parameters to the Driver that references the object's own Properties, you have to specify which object to take the properties from by hand for *every* object, which completely negates the modularity I was aiming for in the first place.

Is this the correct thing to attempt? Is there a better tool to make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's what `self` is for - in driver, you need to enable *"Use Self"* and then access your custom properties by `self["property_name"]`

[image]

Comment: love the video explanation! ;)

Comment: @Chris Me too. If I try something like that, it usually winds up being take 17.. :(