# How to detect active modifier changed

Tags: python, scripting

My goal is to print out a message when you click on the UI to change the active modifier.

[image]

I tried different methods but failed

```
import bpy

def message_callback(*k, **kw):
    print("You changed the active modifier by clicking through the UI!")

# method 1
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=(bpy.types.ObjectModifiers, "active"),
    owner="method_1",
    args=(),
    notify=message_callback)

# method 2
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=bpy.context.object.modifiers.active,
    owner="method_2",
    args=(),
    notify=message_callback)

# method 3
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(message_callback)
```

##### Finally I thought of a way

I provided a draw level solution below, but the performance was poor since the draw function will run a lot on some operations, so I'm looking for another answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically run a script when an object is transformed or a condition is met](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249809/automatically-run-a-script-when-an-object-is-transformed-or-a-condition-is-met) - one approach would be to set up (could be programmatically) a driver with a variable being a property of the modifier? Not sure if just any property will work, or you need to set up variables for all of them. On the opposing end of the spectrum, you could use a view draw handler hack.

Comment: I'm not considering using the Driver method since I'm using it in addon development. imagine users deleting this driver will then cause some problems, but thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Check all objects on draw level with poor performance

```
import bpy
DATA = {}

def message_callback(*k, **kw):
    print("You changed the active modifier by clicking through the UI!")

def check_all_objects():
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        if hasattr(ob, "modifiers"):
            if hasattr(ob.modifiers, "active"): # need check, In old version blend file, It is possible that only a few objects have this property and others do not
                if ob in DATA and DATA[ob] == ob.modifiers.active: continue

                store_data()
                return True
    return False

def store_data():
    DATA.clear()
    DATA.update({ob: ob.modifiers.active for ob in bpy.data.objects
        if hasattr(ob, "modifiers") and hasattr(ob.modifiers, "active")
    })

def draw():
    print('draw')
    
    if check_all_objects():
        message_callback()

# doesn't work if no viewport
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

##### Finally found a good solution that works for me

```
ACT_MD = [None]
def draw_callback(self, context):
    ob = context.object
    if hasattr(ob, "modifiers") and hasattr(ob.modifiers, "active"):
        if ob.modifiers.active != ACT_MD[0]:
            print('active object changed or active modifier changed!!')
            ACT_MD[0] = ob.modifiers.active

bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append(draw_callback)
```

Comment: Iterating over all objects is harsh on every redraw. Maybe it would be enough to only check the active object? After all when you check the active modifier, you do in on the active object, right?

Comment: You are right, i forgot this. Can't seem to change the active modifier without changing the active object in UI.

Comment: Well you can change the modifiers on an inactive object, if you pin the panel using the button in the top right, but it's a rather extreme usecase and I don't think many people even know it exists. Depends on your workflow.