# Python : How to subscribe to perspective change in 3d view area?

Tags: python

I want to listen for a change of perspective in the 3d area, maybe can use msgbus api.The code I try as followed.But it does't work.How can I choose the correct properties.

````
def notify_test(*args):
    print('change123')
    
subscribe_to = bpy.types.RegionView3D,'view_rotation'
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=object(),
        args=(1, 2, 3),
        notify=notify_test,
    )
bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
```
````

Comment: Some suggestions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249814/60486

Comment: Yup I think the only one which will work here is the 3D view handler. The depsgraph doesn't get updated when the viewport camera moves and I wouldn't count on msgbus.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you for your helpful suggestiion! I will learn more about them.

Comment: @Gorgious Oh. thanks.Moreover, is there any links for me to learn about the 3D view handler?